# Extract from the first brackets from a Google Sheet cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-workspace

I have the following strings in cells in Google Sheet (excluding the double quotes).

"Remote Copy Group 156(nw-prd-db) Degraded (Periodic Sync Took More Than Sync Period {0x7})"
"Remote Copy Group 178(fr-prd-db) Degraded (Periodic Sync Took More Than Sync Period {0x7})"

I wish to extract only "nw-prd-db" or "fr-prd-db" from the strings.
How can it be done?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have one of these in each cell (for example, in `A1`), you can use the following regular expression with [REGEXEXTRACT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en):

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"\((.+?)\)")
```

[image]

- This matches one to unlimited characters inside a `( )` (for which escape character is used `\(`, `\)`. And `?` makes the pattern "non-greedy", so it will look for the shortest possible match (so it won't extract the rest of the string, until the second `)` at the end).

Or, alternatively:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"\(([^\)]+)\)")
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(FLATTEN(
 SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1, "\d+\(", "♦♣"), "♦")), "♣(.+?)\)")), 
 "where Col1 is not null")))
```

[image]